# Laço entre tabelas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

Bom dia Pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda com SQL Server.

Tenho uma Tabela AAA, que me retornar itens e uma BBB que me retorna usuários, como faço para repetir todos os usuários para cada item?
Obs: essas tabelas não tem amarrações !

EX:

JOAO  - ITEM A
JOAO  - ITEM B
JOAO  - ITEM C
MARIA - ITEM A
MARIA - ITEM B
MARIA - ITEM C
JOSE  - ITEM A
.
.
.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seria uma query parecida com essa:

```
SELECT item.A, nome.B FROM AAA as A JOIN BBB as B ON user_id.A = id.B
```

Para mais ajuda, posta a estrutura das tabelas. ;)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado @igoriglesias, era basicamente isso só mudei o Join para ON 1=1 !!

SELECT 
 USUARIO,
 ITEM
FROM AAA
INNER JOIN BBB
1 = 1

Vlw mesmo !!

Answer (score -2):

Para esse tipo de caso você pode utilizar um *Cross Join*. Ex:

```
select *
from AAA
cross join BBB
```